Slate JS, How to re-render the context when a change occur in a nodes custom property?
I am using SlateJS with Next(React) to create an editor. I have a custom element defined in the following manner.
// Base Element type
export type CustomBaseElement = {
    type: string;
    children: CustomDescendant[];
    notes: string[];
};

So apart from children, I have a notes property in my custom element that holds a string array.
I have created my custom UI elements (textarea) to render the notes. I am updating the editor on textarea event like so
    const handleInputChange = (event: any) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
        Transforms.setNodes(
            editor,
            { notes: [text] },
            { at: currentSectionHeadingPath }
        );
    };

When I update children on an element, slates useSlate lets me re-render the context and update any components that depend on it. e.g. a button activates only when there is a change in the editor.
However, when I update the notes property, it does not update the editor context. How can I implement the same behaviour with notes?
